# Application pool identity (.net framework 4.0) is giving response timeout exception but network service (frame work 2.0) is working OK

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7.5

We changed framework for our web site from .net 2.0 to 4.0. We had application pool, running under 'network service' for .net 2.0. we are migrating to application pool running under 'Application pool identity' with .net 4.0. Both application pools are in the same server with IIS 7.5.

After migration , we were getting frequent request time out exceptions. Adding the below sections in configuration fixed the issue.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/> 
<compilation debug="false"/>
```

Could you please explain the reason for this timeout exception? Why this is now required in .net 4.0 'Application pool identity' ? Why .NET 2.0 'network service' application pool was working without this segment?

Although we had and still exists the below section in configuration

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
```

we did not have

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
```

Comment: have you tried increasing the timeout value..?

Comment: The executionTimeout default under 2.0 was 90 seconds and under 4.0 is 110 seconds, so that does not explain more timeouts under 4.0.  However, if you compile with debug=true under either environment, execution times will tend to be longer.

Comment: @MethodMan, yes, I did and it is working ok now. However, I will need to explain my upper management the exceptions we had prior to this fix.

Comment: @EricJ., even with debug = true , we were getting response time out exceptions. we  changed debug = false and added executiontimeout to fix timeout exceptions.

Comment: take a look at the link I think that it's related to a 2.0 version of the framework vs some outdated dll or functionality that's been deprecated in 4.0 or maybe even updated https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee941656(v=vs.100).aspx look at the Exceptions section

Comment: I think if your application is in debug mode then you don't need to worry about executionTimeout ideally.

Comment: @HirenDhaduk, true. Thats what I thought too. if we set debug = true and don't keep pdb files inside bin folder-  will that run web site in debug mode? In our case, we did not keep pdb files although we had pdb files with .net 2.0.

Comment: @MethodMan, Thanks ! Looking at that link now.

Comment: debug=true means you are running with debug compilation (.pdb's don't matter), and your execution will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

'network service' and 'Application pool identity' have completely different rights. Are you sure you are not just hitting a security issue which is taking more time to resolve; you are getting an execution timeout - which means your code is taking way too long to execute. Others have commented on using debug code and that being slower - but this will be minute on a normal HTTP endpoint code. I think the timeout might be occurring because of security negotiation. Try changing your Application Pool identity back to Network Service in IIS Manager and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: I am confident that only the below changes were made in web configuration and it fixed the issue. 

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/> 
<compilation debug="false"/>

Comment: Well the default for this in .net 3 was 110 seconds, and in .net 1.0 and 1.1 it was 90 seconds. net 4 and above remained at 110 seconds. So the framework hasn't changed much - therefore your need for a 600s timeout (which is much more than the earlier default of 110s) is indicative of a problem in the setup - you haven't really answered why you now need such a long timeout (which means your code is running slower than it did before) you've just let it have longer before throwing an error. The only other change you mention is security so ... your slow code might be related to security.